# We know that $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=30$ For which value will be $xyz^2$ maximal?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

I don't know how to solve this problem, I have an idea, to search the maxima of $(30-y-z)yz^2$, but I'm not sure about that this is the right way, and how to continue it.

Comment: Hint: Use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: This a good approach I think. Next calculate the gradient.

Comment: Find f'(a) where f(a)=$xyz^2$ and then equate to 0 to find critical points. After finding critical points use them in f''(a) to check maxima and minima.

Comment: i think the proof goes with $$AM-GM$$ or so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach. By arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, we have
$$
\frac{x+y+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}}{4} \geq \sqrt[4]{\frac{xyz^2}{4}} \implies \frac{15^4}{4}\geq xyz^2.
$$

For equality to hold, we must have $x=y=\frac{z}{2}=\frac{15}{2}$. Check that for $(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{15}{2},\frac{15}{2},15\right)$, we indeed attain the maximum, $\frac{15^4}{4}$.